# Logged-in users in Realm Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mobile, realm, mongodb-atlas

I am using Realm Kotlin SDK to authenticate different third party users, like Google and Apple Id. I see in the Kotlin SDK documentation that the last logged-in user is cached along with his/her realm:

> On successful login, the Kotlin SDK caches credentials on the device. You can bypass the login flow and access the cached user. Use this to open a realm or call an Atlas Function upon subsequent app opens.

So logically, on app open, I should check if `app.currentUser` is not null, indicating that there is a logged-in user from a previous session. If it is null, then present the login screen with the various third party auth providers(Google, Apple, etc.) until a user is logged in. Then, start flexible sync with Atlas to get the latest `app.currentUser`'s data and display on UI, until either the user is logged out or the app is closed. Is this the correct approach to authentication and sessions with Realm? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds about right - except that `the app is closed` which goes back to the logged in user is cached after the app is closed. Logging out and closing are two different things. Are you having an issue with your code?

Comment: I meant stop flexible sync until either user is logged out or app is closed, and aso realmUser.logout() on logout. Also, would it make sense to log out of third party authentication after logging out of the app? For example, if I log out of the app AND Google authentication, therefore removing the one-tap login to my Google account if I were want to log in again?

Comment: If you're using Realm for authentication, when you log out, you're logged out. Once logged out your local cache is cleared and app.currentUser will be nil.